# C++ experimenting with insertion sort fail?

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

This code is a direct translation of the pseudo code on Wikipedia. And yet it does not swap any elements. Could someone point me to what is going on?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cctype>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void sortowanie(vector<int> v)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=(int)v.size()-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i; j>0; j--)
        {
            if(v[j-1] > v[j])
            {
                int x = v[j-1];
                v[j-1] = v[j];
                v[j] = x;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(15);
    v.push_back(234);
    v.push_back(21);
    v.push_back(6);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(53);
    v.push_back(23);
    v.push_back(1);

    sortowanie(v);
    for(int i=0; i<=(int)v.size()-1; i++)
    {
        cout << " -> " << v[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing the vector by value, so only a copy is getting sorted. Pass by reference instead. With that one-character change, the output I get is `-> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 15 -> 21 -> 23 -> 53 -> 234`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the `std::vector` by value, so a copy will be made, and changes are only going to be done on **that** copy:

```
void sortowanie(vector<int> v)
```

Add a `&` to use [`pass-by-reference`](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/passing-arguments-by-reference/) instead, so that any change to the `std::vector` inside the function will be applied to the original `std::vector` as well:

```
void sortowanie(vector<int>& v)
```

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void sortowanie(vector<int>& v)
{
    for(size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if(v[j-1] > v[j]) { swap(v[j-1], v[j]); }
            else  {break;}
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v({4,2,15,234,21,6,3,53,23,1});

    sortowanie(v);
    for(int x : v)
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Also, using [`swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) (which by the way use `pass-by-reference` too) and initializer list will shorten the program considerably.

Output : `1 2 3 4 6 15 21 23 53 234`

Comment: `for(int i=1; i<=(int)v.size()-1; i++)` can be cleaned up as well.

Comment: @user4581301 Umm, can I ask how so that I can improve the piece of code above further? I'm not really familiar with shortening and cleaning up code 

Comment: It's mostly to do with the `<=`. That's almost always a bug. The asker resolved it by tacking on a `-1`, but it's better to use the correct test in the first place: `for(int i=1; i<(int)v.size(); i++)`

Comment: @user4581301 Ok!

Comment: A side note is the casting. If change the type of the index variable, the need to cast goes away. `for(size_t i=1; i<=v.size(); i++)` This doesn't always work because sometimes you need `i` to be an `int`, but in this case you just need array indexes and `size_t` fits perfectly.

Comment: Smurf. I left the rogue `=` in there. Code should be `for(size_t i=1; i<v.size(); i++)`